# Ionic / Cordova application testing very slow

Tags: android, angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins, apache-cordova

I'm a newbie with `Ionic / Cordova`.

I tried:

```
$ ionic start ionic2-speed-test-run --v2
$ cd ionic2-speed-test-run/
$ cordova platform add android
$ ionic run android
```

But my problem is that everytime I try to run the application on my `Android` phone to test my changes it takes about `110` seconds.

On my application I want to make use of some `native` functionalities of my phone, like the `camera`, `gps`, etc.

It's not good that everytime I do an small change on my application I need to wait 110 seconds to do tests.

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try Ripple Emulator chrome extension.

You can download it here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc

Comment: does it support Cordova Plugins?, what's the difference of this browser emulator and if I serve the application (to the browser, instead run on my android phone) other than the futures it has on the panels around, for GPS emulation, etc?

Comment: @davidesp yes, it does support cordova plugins. e.g. `cordova-plugin-camera` opens laptop camera.